# How to pass in a dictionary with additional elements in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
big_dict = {1:"1",
            2:"2",
            ...
            1000:"1000"}
```

(Note: My dictionary isn't actually numbers to strings)

I am passing this dictionary into a function that calls for it. I use the dictionary often for different functions. However, on occasion I want to send in `big_dict` with an extra key:item pair such that the dictionary I want to send in would be equivalent to:

```
big_dict[1001]="1001"
```

But I don't want to *actually* add the value to the dictionary. I could make a copy of the dictionary and add it there, but I'd like to avoid the memory + CPU cycles this would consume.

The code I currently have is:

```
big_dict[1001]="1001"
function_that_uses_dict(big_dict)
del big_dict[1001]
```

While this works, it seems rather kludgy.

If this were a string I'd do:

```
function_that_uses_string(myString + 'what I want to add on')
```

Is there any equivalent way of doing this with a dictionary?

Comment: Is the extra key-value pair always the same?

Comment: In this particular case, yes, but I'd like to know how to do it for the general case as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by [Veedrac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763356/veedrac) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27527606/2642204), this problem has already been solved in Python 3.3+ in the form of the [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#chainmap-objects) class:

```
function_that_uses_dict(ChainMap({1001 : "1001"}, big_dict))
```

If you don't have Python 3.3 you should use a backport, and if for some reason you don't want to, then below you can see how to implement it by yourself :)

---

You can create a wrapper, similarly to this:

```
class DictAdditionalValueWrapper:
    def __init__(self, baseDict, specialKey, specialValue):
        self.baseDict = baseDict
        self.specialKey = specialKey
        self.specialValue = specialValue

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == self.specialKey:
            return self.specialValue

        return self.baseDict[key]

    # ...
```

You need to supply all other `dict` method of course, or use the [`UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html) as a base class, which should simplify this.

and then use it like this:

```
function_that_uses_dict(DictAdditionalValueWrapper(big_dict, 1001, "1001"))
```

This can be easily extended to a whole additional dictionary of "special" keys and values, not just single additional element.

---

You can also extend this approach to reach something similar as in your string example:

```
class AdditionalKeyValuePair:
    def __init__(self, specialKey, specialValue):
        self.specialKey = specialKey
        self.specialValue = specialValue

    def __add__(self, d):
        if not isinstance(d, dict):
            raise Exception("Not a dict in AdditionalKeyValuePair")

        return DictAdditionalValueWrapper(d, self.specialKey, self.specialValue)
```

and use it like this:

```
function_that_uses_dict(AdditionalKeyValuePair(1001, "1001") + big_dict)
```

Comment: So in cases I want to use the 'altered' dict I'd use the `DictAdditional..` class and use the regular dict for everything else, yes?

Comment: @musher Yes, exactly. The wrapper is imitating the original dict, slightly altering the behaviour for the special key/value pair. You could even create a `SpecialKeyValuePair` class, and override its `+` operator, so you could have almost the same notation as with string.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on 3.3+, just use [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#chainmap-objects). Otherwise use a backport.

```
new_dict = ChainMap({1001: "1001"}, old_dict)
```

Comment: Any clue where I'd find a backport of ChainMap for 3.1? Or in general

Comment: @Mitch If you don't find something on PyPI, just [copy the code from 3.3/3.4](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/64c0b898c22d3e89ea03335c75580f37e606787d/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L814).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the extra **key-value** pair leaving **original dictionary** as such like this:

```
>>> def function_that_uses_bdict(big_dict):
...    print big_dict[1001]
... 
>>> dct = {1:'1', 2:'2'}
>>> function_that_uses_bdict(dict(dct.items()+[(1001,'1001')]))
1001
>>> dct  
{1: '1', 2: '2'}  # original unchanged
```

Comment: This is cool. Can you do the same with `iteritems` without importing `itertools`?

Comment: This makes a copy of the dict which the user is trying to avoid. Is it faster than dict.copy?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit annoying too, but you could just have the function take two parameters, one of them being big_dict, and another being a temporary dictionary, created just for the function (so something like `fxn(big_dict, {1001,'1001'})` ).  Then you could access both dictionaries without changing your first one, and without copying `big_dict`.